System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException when Form and resx are in project folder
I have a legacy .NET Framework Winforms application that I am migrating from the old csproj file format to the new SDK-Style format.  I did this by creating a new SDK-Style project in the solution with a different name, and then dragging and dropping all the Forms and code files into the new project in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer.  Then I remove the old project and rename the new one (csproj and containing folder) while it's unloaded, then reload it.  This has worked well for me in the past with library projects.  Visual Studio seems to make some adjustments for how the SDK-Style projects handle C# files and embedded resources, such as changing Compile Include to Compile Update, etc.:
old project:
  <Compile Include="EditView.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
  </Compile>

  <Compile Include="EditView.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>EditView.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>

  <EmbeddedResource Include="EditView.resx">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <DependentUpon>EditView.cs</DependentUpon>
  </EmbeddedResource>

new project:
  <Compile Update="EditView.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
  </Compile>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="EditView.resx">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </EmbeddedResource>

But I also have some Forms that are in a project folder and corresponding subdirectory on the file system.
old project:
  <Compile Include="Main Class Files\Main.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="Main Class Files\Main.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Main.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Main Class Files\Main.resx">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <DependentUpon>Main.cs</DependentUpon>
  </EmbeddedResource>

new project:
  <Compile Update="Main Class Files\Main.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
  </Compile>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Main Class Files\Main.resx">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </EmbeddedResource>

This compiles, but at runtime when trying to launching the application in the debugger, it gets the following exception
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "MainApp.Main.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MainApp" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'
I was able to fix this by dragging the Main form out of the project folder and up to the project level, which also moved it out of the subdirectory on the file system.  Other than that, the only change that I can see is that it amended the paths accordingly in the csproj file, removing 'Main Class Files' from Main.cs and Main.resx:
    <Compile Update="Main.cs">
        <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Main.resx">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>

When I did this, VS gave me the option to adjust the namespaces, which I accepted.

At this point, I ran the app again and the fix had worked, but I got the same exception on another Form's resources file that was in a project folder.  I then reasoned that I should be able to drag the form back to it's project folder and decline the namespace adjustment, but VS didn't give me the option.  With the Form and resx back in the project folder, the exception came back.  I'm not sure the namespace option actually made a difference, because these appear to be only string resources and the Access Modifier is set to 'No code generation'.  If there's a namespace associated with them, I can't find it.
This a large, monolithic, legacy application and there are a lot of Forms that are in project folders.  I'd prefer to not have to move the file in the file system since that means I will lose the GitHub history.  Add to that the fact that this is a runtime error and if I miss fixing any of these they could show up later when some affected dialog is opened.  So I'm looking for the most systematic and verifiable way to address this.
So my question is, how can I fix the exception while leaving the files in the subdirectory / project folder, and hopefully find some file in the project where this subdirectory and potentially affected namespace are accounted for so I can ensure I haven't missed any?
Thanks.

Have you tried using the .NET Upgrade Assistant Extension instead of doing it manually? At the start of this year I had to upgrade a very large legacy WinForms app written in VB.NET/C# and this was the only way I didn't run into issue after issue.

I have tried the upgrade assistant in the past, but I think it is intended for upgrading the framework you are targeting, e.g. upgrading from net48 to net6.0.  I'm trying to stay on net48 but just update the csproj file format to the new (SDK-Style) format.  Still, I might try this and then just set the tfm back to net48 when it's done if it works.

@DamienD thanks for the suggestion.  I did try it and it has been updated to have a "convert project to sdk" feature (not advertised in the description).  However, while my project did compile after conversion it won't even run, VS shows a dialog box that says it can't be launched (no other error).
